# Why are different Aluminium valencies observed from NMR and what logic can be used to normalise molar ratios of different valency atoms?

Tags: electrons, nmr-spectroscopy, materials, covalent-compounds, valence-bond-theory

**Question 1:**

I've observed different chemical shifts in 27Al Nuclear Magnetic Resonance (NMR) spectra of commercial aqueous sodium aluminate, indicating the presence of both trivalent [Al(III)] and tetravalent [Al(IV)] aluminium bonds with different numbers of other atoms which is consistent with 27Al NMR seen in literature ([Source1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265076752_Geopolymer_Chemistry_and_Applications), [Source2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8658912/)). However, considering aluminium's position in the periodic table with the $Al^{3+}$ charge (which is not 4+), why isn't Al(III) the only existing valence state for aluminium? What factors lead to the coexistence of both trivalent and tetravalent forms of Al?

**Question 2:**

An experimentally inferred (and generally accepted within literature) geopolymer structure can be observed below from [Barbosa et al](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1466604900000416) where an ideal geopolymer has $Al^{3+}$ in four-fold coordination but that the observed Al coordination can change depending on how the "activator solution" (essentially a chemical catalyst of sorts) is synthesised. Their proposed geopolymer structure in Figure 8 (below) had both $SiQ^4(3Al)$ and $SiQ^4(2Al)$.

[image: From Barbosa et al]

It is conventional in geopolymer systems to specify a system molar Si/Al ratio when combining feedstocks and assumes that the covalent bonds formed is as dictated by an element's valence electron number and charge as follows:

$$\\\left(\frac{n_{Si}}{n_{Al}}\right)_{Conventional} = \frac{n_{Si^{4+}}}{n_{Al^{3+}}} \approx \frac{n_{Si(IV)}}{n_{Al(III)}}\\\\$$

Usually, $Na^+$ is added to the system via a $\frac{Na}{Al}$ ratio to provide charge balance with the $Si^{4-}$ and $Al^{3+}$ for the system to theoretically neutralise. However, the information from Q1 above shows that some of the $Al$ can have different valencies and thus form covalent bonds differently in the system. Assuming the molar trivalent and tetravalent Al can be quantified via quantitative NMR, does it make sense for the $\frac{Si}{Al}$ ratio instead be normalised as follows:

$$\\\left(\frac{n_{Si}}{n_{Al}}\right)_{Normalised} \approx \frac
{n_{Si(IV)}}
{(n_{Al(III)} \times \frac{3 bonds Al}{4 bonds Si}) + (n_{Al(IV)} \times \frac{4 bonds Al}{4 bonds Si})} 
= 
\frac{n_{Si(IV)}}
{(n_{Al(III)} \times \frac{3}{4}) + n_{Al(IV)}}\\\\$$

So, with the information above, is it reasonable to presume that the molar ratios should be normalised to account for different Al valencies which lead to different coordinations in the final geopolymer structure?
If the above is true then the other molar ratios, such as the $\frac{Na}{Al}$ would have to also be normalised.

Comment: 'Tetravalent' doesn't mean $\ce{Al^{4+}}$, it just means aluminium bonded to four things. $\ce{[Al(OH)4]^-}$, for example, is tetravalent $\ce{Al^3+}$. Quoting from your Source 2: *"The oxygen tetrahedra holding $\ce{Al^3+}$ ions hold a negative charge that is neutralized by an alkali metal cation."*

Comment: Thank you for the correction, what is the term I'm looking for then? Or should I just be referencing the numerical charge?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to describe? If you're talking about aluminium bound to four things, then tetravalent is just fine. If you're talking about $\ce{Al^4+}$ then yes, use the charge. But the latter doesn't exist, so maybe it's worth reworking the question a bit — in particular, your first question — because there's no contradiction between Al being in Group 13 and Al being tetravalent.

Comment: I have edited the question with the Al(III) and Al(IV) (etc.) terminology as appropriate for valency, thanks for letting me know. I was getting mixed up with charge. :)

Comment: I'm getting requests to close the thread but no feedback onto why specifically it should be closed. What can I be more specific on?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the different <sup>27</sup>Al resonances you observed are due to varying oxidation numbers? While I don't have a complete understanding of the materials you are using, I do have experience with zeolites and other Al oxides, and in my experience, distinct regions of the spectra usually suggest different coordination of Al. For instance, 4-coordinated Al is typically present in the range of 70-50 ppm, 5-coordinated Al is found in the range of 40-20 ppm, and 6-coordinated Al is usually in the range of 10 to -10 ppm. Here is a [nice review on <sup>27</sup>Al NMR of materials](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pnmrs.2016.01.003), in Figure 2 they discuss the chemical shift range of different Al species.

Bear in mind that <sup>27</sup>Al is a quadrupolar nucleus, which means that you may have a quadrupolar broadening of your resonances. Additionally, what may appear to be a broad resonance can often be the result of a distribution of chemical environments. [Czjzek's distribution is commonly used to deconvolute <sup>27</sup>Al spectra of glasses and other Al oxides](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmr.2008.03.001), separating the contributions from local coordination environments. You can apply this to your spectra using freely available software such as [DMFit](https://nmr.cemhti.cnrs-orleans.fr/dmfit/) and [ssNake](https://www.ru.nl/science/magneticresonance/software/ssnake/).

Comment: I just made an edit to my question for clarity. The feedstock I'm using is commercially available aqueous sodium aluminate (as the primary source of soluble Al). Yes I think your answer is on the right track and answers the first part of my question.

Comment: I would not expect to have Al$^{3+}$ on the geopolymer. I would assume that you have a chemical analysis of the polymer so the Si/Al ratio should be just the molar amount of each element, independently of their coordination/valence. Then if you can make some quantification for $^{27}$Al NMR you can just decompose the total amount of Al, however, that should not change the total Si/Al ratio.

Comment: A good description of the geopolymer species is given by Barbosa et al (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1466604900000416) where an ideal geopolymer has $Al^{3+}$ in four-fold coordination but that it can change depending on how the "activator solution" (essentially a chemical catalyst of sorts) is synthesised. Their proposed geopolymer structure in Figure 8 had both $SiQ^4(3Al)$ and $SiQ^4(2Al)$. So, with this information, shouldn't the Si/Al be normalised?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand your question. Those SiQ4 species you indicate are just Si atoms surrounded by either 2 or 3 Al, nothing related to the oxidation state of Al. If that is the case maybe you can use the equation used in molecular sieves to determine Si/Al ratio from $^{29}$Si NMR

$$Si/Al = \frac{I_{Q4(0Al)} + I_{Q4(1Al)} + I_{Q4(2Al)} + I_{Q4(3Al)} + I_{Q4(4Al)}}{0.25*I_{Q4(1Al)} + 0.5*I_{Q4(2Al)} + 0.75*I_{Q4(3Al)} + I_{Q4(4Al)}}$$

Comment: Interesting comment! This might be what I'm looking for. I'm essentially just trying to more accurately define the Si and Al (and ideally also OH but this is out of scope for this question) that is available for reaction so that I can more accurately define my system; bigger $Q^n$ species are harder to breakdown and thus not available for reaction (sources). Could you please provide more information (either via these comments or an answer to the thread) and a reference of some sort so I can follow up and research this for better understanding before I come back with another comment?

Comment: You can find it for example in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1039/F29827801025)